# First Fundamental Theorem of Calculus very simple question

Tags: integration

From

https://ximera.osu.edu/mooculus/calculus1/secondFundamentalTheoremOfCalculus/digInSecondFundamentalTheoremOfCalculus

given $a\le c\le b$

$$\begin{align*} 
         \int_a^b f(x) d x &= \int_a^c f(x) d x + \int_c^b f(x) d x \\
      &= \int_c^b f(x) d x - \int_c^a f(x) d x.
    \end{align*}\tag1$$

By the First Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, we have

$$F(b) = \int _c^b f(x) d x\qquad \text {and}\qquad F(a) = \int _c^a f(x) d x\tag2$$

for some antiderivative *F* of *f*. So

$$\int _a^b f(x) d x = F(b)-F(a)\tag3$$

*MY QUESTION: Is equation 2 wrong?* I think the left hand sides of the two equations should be $F(b) - F(c)$ and $F(a) - F(c)$.

Comment: The First Fundamental Theorem of Calculus tells you that $\int_c^b f(x)\,dx = F(b)-F(c)$, not $F(b)$; and $\int_c^a f(x)\,dx = F(a)-F(c)$, not just $F(a)$. So you are correct that (2) is incorrect.

Comment: "For some antiderivative".

Comment: @ Andrés E. Caicedo Excuse me, but what does that mean?

Comment: There is exactly one antiderivative $F$ with the property that $F(c)=0$, and that is the function the author is using.

Comment: @ Andrés E. Caicedo But $[F(b)−F(c)] - [F(a)−F(c)] = F(b)- F(a)$ for any value of $F(c)$.

Answer (score 1):

The first fundamental theorem tells you that, under reasonable assumptions on $f$ (say, continuity), for any point $t_0$ in the interval of definition of $f$, the function $$ G(x)=\int_{t_0}^x f(s)\,ds $$ is an antiderivative of $f$.

In the text in question, the author is simply taking $t_0=c$.

(Now, once you know $f$ has an antiderivative $G$, for any constant $\alpha$ the function $\alpha+G$ is another antiderivative of $f$, so if all one wanted was an antiderivative vanishing at $c$, choosing $\alpha$ carefully would take care of it. But note that the goal of the author is a bit more, namely, to prove the second fundamental theorem, so he needs the specific formula for $G$ that the first fundamental theorem gives us. The point $c$ that plays here the role of what I called $t_0$ is irrelevant, of course.)